# Create a copy of CMSampleBuffer in Swift 2.0

Tags: ios, swift2, avfoundation, unsafe-pointers, core-media

This has been asked before, but something must have changed in Swift since it was asked. I am trying to store `CMSampleBuffer` objects returned from an `AVCaptureSession` to be processed later. After some experimentation I discovered that `AVCaptureSession` must be reusing its `CMSampleBuffer` references. When I try to keep more than 15 the session hangs. So I thought I would make copies of the sample buffers. But I can't seem to get it to work. Here is what I have written:

```
var allocator: Unmanaged<CFAllocator>! = CFAllocatorGetDefault()
var bufferCopy: UnsafeMutablePointer<CMSampleBuffer?>
let err = CMSampleBufferCreateCopy(allocator.takeRetainedValue(), sampleBuffer, bufferCopy)
if err == noErr {
    bufferArray.append(bufferCopy.memory!)
} else {
    NSLog("Failed to copy buffer. Error: \(err)")
}
```

This won't compile because it says that `Variable 'bufferCopy' used before being initialized`. I've looked at many examples and they'll either compile and not work or they won't compile.

Anyone see what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Literally you're attempting to use the variable bufferCopy before it is initialized.

You've declared a type for it, but haven't allocated the memory it's pointing to.

You should instead create CMSampleBuffers using the following call https://developer.apple.com/library/tvos/documentation/CoreMedia/Reference/CMSampleBuffer/index.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CMSampleBufferCreate

You should be able to copy the buffer into this then (as long as the format of the buffer matches the one you're copying from).

Comment: Thanks for the response Tim, this seems like it may be a good solution for a deep clone. But I'm not that familiar with the way the memory is used at this level. Do you know where I might find a decent example of how to create a deep clone of a `CMSampleBuffer` for both video and audio? Apple apparently holds a cache of 15 `CMSampleBuffer`s that it recycles when running the `AVCaptureSession`. I will evidently need to deep clone to store my own.

Comment: I finally figured out how to use this to create a deep clone. All the copy methods reused the data in the heap which kept would lock the `AVCaptureSession`. So I had to pull the data out into a `NSMutableData` object and then created a new sample buffer. Thanks

Comment: @Rob could you add your code for deep cloning. I have the same issue and am already searching for half a day.

Comment: @Rob, your exact procedure has been asked about in a follow-up question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38335365/ Perhaps you'd like to post an answer there?

Comment: @Rob, Can you share please your solution

Answer (score 8):

You can simply pass a `CMSampleBuffer?` variable (which, as an optional,
is implicitly initialized with `nil`) as inout argument with
`&`:

```
var bufferCopy : CMSampleBuffer?
let err = CMSampleBufferCreateCopy(kCFAllocatorDefault, buffer, &bufferCopy)
if err == noErr {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you. This answered the problem I had above for getting the code to compile. And when I test ran the code it turns out that it must be a shallow clone. The data that the new `CMSampleBuffer` held was in the same location as the previous. So when I ran the `AVCaptureSession` it sent 15 sample and locked again because I was holding the reference to the underlying data location. Any idea how I can create a deep clone so I can duplicate the data into a new location in memory? Thanks!